# What to do after realizing to have opened two "similar" questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

Some days ago I've opened a question titled "[How to properly define a TCustomFrame's child class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544494/how-to-properly-define-a-tcustomframes-child-class)" in which I've explained my attempt and the error message that was blocking me.

Thanks to Sertac Akyuz's answer, I've resolved the error and I've accepted its answer. Unfortunately, I found other problems and I've (wrongly?) opened  another, a little more specific, question titled "[Why a component inherited from TCustomFrame looks different from TFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586128/why-a-component-inherited-from-tcustomframe-looks-different-from-tframe)".

I received some downvotes and Sertac Akyuz said that I should unaccept his answer to my first question because it wasn't fully solving the problem (And I suppose someone have seen my second question as a duplicate of the first question).

I agree with him but what to do with the second question?
Should I delete it, close it or what else?

Comment: If it's two different problems, even if one resulted from fixing the first, I don't see much wrong with opening a new question. However, I don't know much about these technologies, so I could be wrong about them being different enough.

Comment: I mean in general you should test the answer before you accept it to make sure it helped you. If it helped you a certain way this is OK. But if the answer turns out to be wrong/incomplete it may be valid to unaccept this. You should take care though, that you just not edit the question in a way that it changes the question too much. If you first question could help others with a similar problem and your specification shines a different light in the whole problem having 2 questions is fine. It depends in how much value for others your first question could have.

Comment: AFAIK first question is asked in such manner that even though answer does not solve your problem completely, explains to extent what is happening and why you are experiencing the issue. Those are two separate questions and it is fine to leave them as they are.

Comment: Downvotes to your question probably come from the fact you are doing something you shouldn't be doing. But the question itself is perfectly acceptable and maybe even answerable by someone that knows inner workings of the system.